# php thread properly run in cmd but don't run in browser. And gives "Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2" error

Tags: php

```
 <?php
 class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
   public function __construct($arg){
     $this->arg = $arg;
   }
   public function run(){
     if($this->arg){
      for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        echo "-> " . $this->arg . "\n";
       sleep(1);
     }
    }
  }
}
flush();
$thread = new AsyncOperation("Thread 1");
$thread2 = new AsyncOperation("Thread 2");
$thread->start();
$thread2->start();
$thread->join();
$thread2->join();
?>
```

**My PHP VERSION 7.2.11**

*Compiler: MSVC15(Visual C++ 2017)  and Architecture: x86 *

> Blockquote

1. Copy "pthreadVC2.dll" from "php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.2-ts-vc15-x86" and Paste to "C:\xampp\php" Folder.
2. Copy "php_pthreads.dll" from "php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.2-ts-vc15-x86" and Paste to "C:\xampp\php\ext" Folder
3. Open "php.ini" file with notepad or notepad++ and configur  "extension=php_pthreads.dll"
4. & Save the "php.ini" file.

Comment: do you have the apache server running in the xamp control panel?

Comment: yes,apache server is running all that time.

Comment: have you tried restarting apache, and or your computer?

Comment: yes, i try that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if pthreads is only for running in cli and not on a webserver.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

> Warning The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server
>   environment. Threading in PHP is therefore restricted to CLI-based
>   applications only.
>
> Warning pthreads (v3) can only be used with PHP 7.2+: This is due to
>   ZTS mode being unsafe in 7.0 and 7.1.